# Rails route for nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes

I have a rails model that is nested:

```
# app/models/frontend/item.rb
class Frontend::Item < Item
end
```

When I call

```
form_for(@frontend_item)
```

It tries to go to the **'/frontend/items'** path.

Is there a way to make it go to **'/items'** instead (without the inherited '/frontend')

Comment: You seem to be confusing resources and models. Models are not nested, but contained. So, your FrontEnd contains items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a scope section:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope :module => "frontend", :as => 'frontend' do
  resources :items
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have done this already but you tried

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Not sure how seeing the routes will help.. can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice example of precisely what you want in the rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

~Charles~

Comment: I fail to see an example of that.. note that I am nesting Models not resources in routes.

Answer (score 0):

You've explicitly namespaced a `Frontend::Item` as a separate model from `Item`.  Thus, a `frontend_item` properly routes to `/frontend/items/:id`.

To override that, add the following line to your routes file:

```
# routes.rb
match 'item/:id' => 'Frontend::Item#show'
```

Note that this will now conflict with the route for your `Item` model so you should remove that route.